# How to update PR from which I deleted the source in GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have opened a PR a few weeks ago. I deleted my local stuff. Now I need to update the PR. How can I do this?

- I took a new fork
- I checked out the PR (`gh pr checkout xxx`)
- I made my changes and commited
- I wanted to push but I got:

  fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
  the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
  on the remote, use

  ```
    git push git@github.com:xx/yyy.git HEAD:refs/pull/111/head
  ```

  To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

  ```
    git push git@github.com:xx/yyy.git HEAD
  ```

But when I try that I get

```
ERROR: Permission to xx/yyy.git denied to my-user.
```

I can push the branch to my own fork but then I can only create a new PR? What steps should I follow to update my PR from which I don't have a fork anymore and there is no branch.

Comment: If you deleted your previous fork, you have no repository on GitHub and cannot update your old PR (nor can you close it nor do anything at all with it). You can create a new fork and a new PR, but that's all.

Comment: I can not update my PR when I deleted that old fork? :(

Comment: As far as I know, anyway. The problem is that deleting a GitHub repository doesn't actually *delete* it, it just transfers ownership to the next fork up or down, as it were. That's due to the internal way GitHub implements forks to save themselves disk space.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a ticket and they confirmed it and will put back the fork in a state that I can continue with it.